# Why is my Reverse Function Reversing All my Pairs BESIDES One?

Tags: scheme, racket, computer-science, r5rs

i.e. I am given this (all possible combinations to make change for 11):

```
(list 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 10 10 10 1 1 25 25 25 25 25 25)
```

My code should return:

```
((7 . 1) (4 . 5) (3 . 1) (3 . 10) (2 . 1) (6 . 25))
```

so it is more readable.

However, it is returning:

```
((7 . 1) (4 . 5) (1 . 3) (3 . 10) (2 . 1) (6 . 25))
```

I don't know how to reverse the order of ALL my pairs.

This is my code:

```
(define (rev pair) ;; function reverses a pair, not a list.
   (map (lambda (e) (cons (cdr e) (car e))) pair)) 
(define (rle coins)
  (if (null? coins)
      '()
      (let loop ((firsts (list (car coins)))
                 (but-firsts (cdr coins)))
        (if (or (null? but-firsts)
                (not (equal? (car firsts) (car but-firsts))))
            (rev (cons (cons (car firsts) (length firsts))
                       (rle but-firsts)))
            (rev (loop (cons (car but-firsts) firsts) (cdr but-firsts)))))))
```

This is my test:

```
(rle (list 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 10 10 10 1 1 25 25 25 25 25 25))
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but it's possible the `rev` function is reversing that pair just fine, but the `rle` / `loop` recursion happens to call `rev` twice on that pair, to switch it back to the original. Or, somehow it's calling `rev` an even number of times on lists with that pair, but an odd number of times on lists with the other pairs

Answer (score 0):

Why not writing a classical tail-call recursive function?
Because my opinion is that named-loops are horrible constructs - unclear for the reader.

```
(define (rle coins (acc '()))
  (if (null? coins)
      (reverse acc)
      (rle (cdr coins)
           (if (and (not (null? acc)) (equal? (cdar acc) (car coins)))
               (cons (cons (+ 1 (caar acc)) 
                           (cdar acc))
                     (cdr acc))
               (cons (cons 1 (car coins))
                           acc)))))
```

It does correctly:

```
(rle (list 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 10 10 10 1 1 25 25 25 25 25 25))
;; '((7 . 1) (4 . 5) (3 . 1) (3 . 10) (2 . 1) (6 . 25))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some systematic testing (test cases should be systematic and as small as possible, not large and arbitrary):

```
> (rle '(2))
'((1 . 2))
> (rle '(2 3))
'((1 . 2) (3 . 1))
> (rle '(2 3 4))
'((1 . 2) (3 . 1) (1 . 4))
> (rle '(2 3 4 5))
'((1 . 2) (3 . 1) (1 . 4) (5 . 1))
> (rle '(2 3 4 5 6))
'((1 . 2) (3 . 1) (1 . 4) (5 . 1) (1 . 6))
```

When all the elements are unique, it looks like every other element is backwards.

```
> (rle '(5 5 6))
'((5 . 2) (1 . 6))
> (rle '(5 5 6 6))
'((5 . 2) (6 . 2))
> (rle '(5 5 6 6 6))
'((5 . 2) (3 . 6))
> (rle '(5 6 6 6))
'((1 . 5) (6 . 3))
```

When elements are repeated, the order seems a bit unpredictable.

Let's count how many times you `rev` each element by using triple elements with the counter as the `car`:

```
;; Flip the order of a pair.
(define (flip x)
  (cons (cdr x) (car x)))

;; Add one to the car of each element and flip its cdr.
(define (rev list)
  (map (lambda (x) (cons (+ 1 (car x)) (flip (cdr x)))) list))

(define (rle coins)
  (if (null? coins)
      '()
      (let loop ((firsts (list (car coins)))
                 (but-firsts (cdr coins)))
        (if (or (null? but-firsts)
                (not (equal? (car firsts) (car but-firsts))))
            (rev (cons (cons 0 (cons (car firsts) (length firsts)))
                       (rle but-firsts)))
            (rev (loop (cons (car but-firsts) firsts) (cdr but-firsts)))))))
```

This creates a list that says how many times `rev` has been applied to each element in the result.

```
> (rle '(99))
'((1 1 . 99))
> (rle '(99 99))
'((2 99 . 2))
> (rle '(99 99 99))
'((3 3 . 99))
> (rle '(99 99 99 100))
'((3 3 . 99) (4 100 . 1))
> (rle '(99 99 99 100 100))
'((3 3 . 99) (5 2 . 100))
```

As you can see, each element has been "flipped" many times - once for every time you recurse.
This happens because you apply `rev` to every partial result, and not just on the final list.
The elements that have been flipped an even number of times are "backwards".

Now, your example input:

```
> (rle (list 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 10 10 10 1 1 25 25 25 25 25 25))
'((7 7 . 1) (11 4 . 5) (14 1 . 3) (17 3 . 10) (19 2 . 1) (25 6 . 25))
```

where we can see that the third element has been flipped an even number of times, and this is what's causing it to be backwards.

The best solution is to build your pairs in the order you want them, so you don't need to adjust them afterwards; the implementation is left as an exercise.
(The implementation is a very minor change in your procedure, and the removal of `rev`.)